# Displaying Image on SharePoint page from another SharePoint site (Of different Farm)

Tags: sharepoint-server, javascript, authentication

We have two different SharePoint server on different farm. We want to take images from one SharePoint site library and display it on another site page. We have given URL of images on page but it is not showing image until we visit source site at least once. Can somebody knows how to authenticate one user using JavaScript on source site instead of visiting site in browser?